# How to add core data to existing project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, addition

Hai I already created a project in Xcode and it is 3/4th completed.I have not enabled `Use Core Data` option when creating a project.Now I am in need to add the core data to the project.Is there any way to add it to my project?I am using Xcode 11.3.1.Please help me...Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to do it manually as far as I know, one way is to create a new core data project and use that as a template as for what you need to add.